# How to make an image compression algorithm?

Tags: java, c, image, algorithm, compression

I wonder how image compression algorithms are made and I would like to make some research about it, and, perhaps, try to make a rudimentary compression program by myself.

All my researches lead to articles about "how to order a JPEG compression with Java", while I actually want to create the compression process.

I hope I make sense. And please excuse any language error.

Comment: Ok, but SO doesn't like such super-broad questions. Try reading stuff on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to learn about compression, I would suggest you start with something easier than the Jpeg Algorithm. In my jounger days, we started with [Huffman](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)
and [Shannon-Fano](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding) coding. But if you feel up to a more challenging start, you can also start with the matrix normalisation of a none lossless compression like jpeg.
In any case, I would rather suggest you use the wikipedia as starting point, than SO.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison Normally I would totally agree with you. My hope is, that people with the same question will be directly redirected to wiki when reading the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I will take a look at your links first.